# How to generate migration files using schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake

Suppose I have a Big and Ugly schema.rb, and no migrations, what is the best way of creating them, besides doing this with ctr+c/crt+v. Plus I need them to be considered as allready migrated :). Consider that this need to be generated in rails 2.3.5 env :(.

Comment: have you run `rake db:schema:load`?

Comment: ...and why is your schema "big and ugly"?

Comment: This is another question ))). This is not my project, I'm doing some refactoring on it. `rake db:schema:load` - will generate migration files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a migration, then copy schema.rb code (without the `ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => x) do` and `end`) into the `up` or `change` method.

Comment: `besides doing this with ctr+c/crt+v`. This will take a lot of time, doing like so.

Comment: `cp db/schema.rb db/migrate/initial_migration.rb`, then edit?

Comment: I get it now. generate a big migration file using big schema file ))). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only option you have is to generate the database from your schema.rb file using the command `rake db:schema:load`. Just be careful as `rake db:schema:load` will delete data on your production server.

If you look at the schema.rb file you will notice it only has the timestamp of the last migration, which is the version of the schema, and the commands required to replicate it. You can create a single migration from it, and make all the future changes from there.